# Concatenating rows from an alias computed column

Tags: sql-server, substring, concatenation, calculated-columns, sql-server-2008

I have two tables, one named Car and one named Mileage. Car table has the following column:
`CarName varchar(max)`
Mileage table has the following columns:
`CarMileage int
CarName varchar(max)
TotalGasTrips int` 
 My code is the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT y.CarName,
                Substring((SELECT ', ' + Cast(c.MPG AS VARCHAR(max))
                           FROM   Mileage
                                  JOIN Car
                                    ON Mileage.CarName = Car.CarName
                           WHERE  Mileage.CarName = Car.CarName
                           FOR xml path ('')), 2, 1000) AS MPGString
FROM   Car y
       INNER JOIN (SELECT w.CarName,
                          CarMileage / TotalGasTrips AS MPG
                   FROM   Mileage w
                   GROUP  BY w.CarName,
                             w.CarMileage,
                             w.TotalGasTrips)c
               ON y.CarName = c.CarName
GROUP  BY c.MPG,
          y.CarName
```

The query result is:

```
CarName      MPGString
Acura NSX    20,20,20,20
Acura NSX    42,42,42,42
Pagani Zonda 24,24,24,24
Pagani Zonda 43,43,43,43
```

The result I want is:

```
CarName     MPGString
Acura NSX    20,42
Pagani Zonda 24,43
```

Is it possible to get the correct concatenated rows I want from aliased computed columns? I tried looking all over and all I found was concatenation from columns that already had existing values and not from computed columns.  Thanks for your help.

**Edit:**
Both tables have the same car names ( in this instance Acura NSX and Pagani Zonda).To test the string concatenation, I gave the same two cars different numbers for TripGasTrips and CarMileage.  An example is the following in the Mileage table:
`Acura NSX 125471,6172
Acura NSX 213776,5000
Pagani Zonda 166793, 6911
Pagani Zonda 315531 7312`

with the columns being CarName, CarMileage and TotalGasTrips respectively
and in the Car Table I have the following:
`Acura NSX
Pagani Zonda`
with CarName being the only column for the table.
**Edit:**
Output from the c table is as follows:

`CarName MPG
Acura NSX 20
Acura NSX 42
Pagani Zonda 24
Pagani Zonda 43`

Comment: What is the output of `C` table

Comment: @NoDisplayName edited the result of c table into question.

Comment: Is your `carname` column in `car` table values are distinct

Comment: Yes, the values are distinct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me (it would be easier if you gave some data to test with):

```
SELECT
  C.CarName,
  SUBSTRING((
             SELECT
              ', ' + CAST(CarMileage / TotalGasTrips AS VARCHAR(MAX))
             FROM
              Mileage
             WHERE
              Mileage.CarName = C.CarName
             GROUP BY
              dbo.Mileage.CarMileage,
              dbo.Mileage.TotalGasTrips
            FOR
             XML PATH('')
            ), 2, 1000) AS MPGString
FROM
  Car C
  JOIN dbo.Mileage M ON C.CarName = M.CarName
GROUP BY
  C.CarName
```

Comment: Perfect.  This gave me the answer I was looking for.